# Is it possible to find out a user's router's MAC address?

Tags: php, ip-address, router, mac-address

I would like to use a PHP script to find the router that a user is connected to my site from. Is this possible with PHP or some other Server-Side language?

I have looked online and it looks like its not possible to get if for the user's computer, but for the router?
EDIT: I am only interested in the user's router, not the user's specific computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't find the destination user `MAC` because `MAC` is only usable in *local network packet exchaning*, in `WAN` network you use `IP` to *packet exchanging* then you can only get `IP` of her router.

But is a exception from this rule, **if you are with user in local network** (eg. server is in local network) **then you can get `MAC` address of client or router by look at `ARP` table**, in her you have `IP` addresses of local computers and her `MAC's`, from this table you can get her router `MAC` by finding in `ARP` table `Gateway IP` association, because her gateway is a your gateway and gateway is a router in your network and her network too because you is in same network with client..

But at all this is nonsense in this case because communication with user and server is a local, then packets will not reach the router, but if you really want this you can get this.

Second nonsense is if you are in local network with user (only one option to solve this problem) then probably gateway address will be constant always. This can make change if someone change a router device to other.;-)

**Summary:** You can solve this problem but only if server and user is in a local network, but i think you want solve this problem for `WAN` network, then you can't do this ... sorry is not me choice, live is brutal.

Comment: I am not interested in the user, just the router.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot find it out as the only MAC address the server sees is that of the router it is connected to which is usually **far** away from the user's hardware. So you would always get the same MAC address.

Comment: I am only looking for the router's MAC address

Comment: As I said, you can only get the MAC of the router your **server** is connected to. Not the one of the user. Obviously this doesn't apply if the user is in the same LAN as the server (home/company network for example)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible because the MAC address is not included in the headers sent to your server.  IP address or cookie tracking is the best you've got available to uniquely identify anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be on the same network as the user, or the user's router. This could likely be accomplished only through malicious means, as this defeats the entire purpose of the encapsulation provided by the OSI hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The router may embed it's MAC address in it IPv6 address, which could be discovered using traceroute.

You can find out the MAC address of the routers on your local network, you will not find the MAC address of the router the user's computer is connected to.